# Why does header show +6 but Answer show -1

Tags: support, reputation

For this answer... https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/2215/3640

Admittedly not a great answer, but why does the Achievements rep shows +6 for this answer but the answer itself shows -1. How can that be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reputation:

```
One upvote: +10
Two downvotes: -4
Total: +6
```

Net vote count: -1

Comment: Thank You. Seems I'm forever confusing number-of-votes with rep-per-vote. "Of all the things I've lost in life, my mind's the one I miss the most. -- unknown"

Comment: Never mind. It's just imaginary internet points after all, @DocSalvager